# "Token invalid - Invalid token: Secure token but no target found" error thrown while using PicasaService.Query()

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, picasa

I am getting the above mentioned error while trying to use **PicasaService.Query(query)** method using **Oauth 2.0 token**. I am trying to list all the albums in authenticated user's account.
Following is the code :

```
        AlbumQuery query = new AlbumQuery(AlbumQuery.CreatePicasaUri(userId));
        PicasaFeed picasaAlbumList = service.Query(query);
```

where service is

```
    public static PicasaService service;
```

I am using the latest version of **Google.Gdata.Client**, **Google.Gdata.Extensions**,**Google.Gdata.Photos**. It was working all fine with OAuth 1.0 token untill and unless OAuth 1.0 was completely deprecated.

Now its throwing the following error after implementing the user authentication using Oauth 2.0

```
    Token invalid - Invalid token: Secure token but no target found
```

Is this error due to some missing parameter while making the token request or the error because of the Google.Gdata libraries? Could not find much information on this error over the net.

> PS: I am using the client-ID and client-secret created for 'native
>   application' in Google Developer Console.

Any suggestion or pointers will be of great help. Thanks a ton in advance!